# Secured virtual disk on windows with VC++

Tags: c++, windows, security, file-access

I have a DLL of a software that I want to use. In the DLL API there is a function "LoadConfigFile(char* file)" which needs a filename with aboslute path to it (e.g "C:\TestFolder\ConfigFile.cfg"). The function then loads the config file itself.

Due to security reasons I want to allow the access to the file (content) only to the program in which the DLL is used.

So I was wondering how this could be done and searched the internet for solutions. The following options and questions came to mind while looking for a solutions:

- I could encrypt the file. -> Does somebody know a free library for this?
  -> Is it then possible to give the function the file as astring and the function     can read the file?
- Maybe there is a possibility of using a virtual file system. What I mean is to load the file from an encrypted source, decrypt it and keep it in RAM on a virtual disk or folder. then give the link as a string to the DLL-function -> Is this possible? -> Does somebody know a free library to do so?
- I also read something about "in memory databases". -> Could this be an answer to my problem?

My development environment is VC++ 2010 and the OS is Windows XP.

I hope someone could help me with this matter.

Comment: So you can't change the software that is actually reading the file (i.e. the DLL) - you don't have access to the source code. Correct?

Comment: That's not going to be secure anyway, since Malware.EXE can also load your DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far too complex. The easiest solution (since you're the process in control) is:

1. Create a temporary file, and open it exclusively (not even share read). Pass `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` since it's not persistent
2. Decrypt the config file to this temporary file. Keep the handle open.
3. Pass the temporary filename to the DLL. It's in your process, so it is not affected by the exclusive lock.
4. When the DLL is done, zero out the temporary file.
5. Close your handle. This will delete the file.

Since the temporary file is locked whenever it contains confidential content, no other process can access it. And since it's marked as temporary, delete on close, Windows won't bother flushing it to physical disk.

Of course, this is not perfect security. Anyone who can read your process memory (i..e has `SeDebugPrivilege`) can access this information, but that's trivially obvious. Just put a debug breakpoint on `LoadConfigFile`.

Comment: Sounds good. I will try it out. The lack of security seems acceptable to me.

Comment: Well, considering your comment to another answer (flashing firmware), it's sufficient security. The data is going to be unencrypted in flash anyway. (My company does embedded products, too, and for security we keep data secured even in flash. There are ARM designs that will do proper crypto including secure boot)

Comment: Make sure that killing your process will close (and delete) the plain text temporary file.

Comment: @ixe013: Killing your process closes all handles, which is why you need `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 1):

How sensitive is your data?  And what is the target for your application?

In many cases a simple home-brew encryption mechanism might be sufficient to scare off the casual reader.

If your data needs thorough encryption, look at the Windows encryption functions (e.g. CryptProtectData, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

In some cases you don't want to encrypt your data, but you just want to make sure that nobody changes it.  In that case, add a hash-value (SHA-2, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) to your file.

Comment: The data must not be readable by third person. If the file is copied it must be encrypted. The file is a firmware of an ebedded device and the target is a production PC with WinXP where the firmware is flashed on the device. The DLL with the function LoadConfigFile(...) is the driver library for the flash device.

Comment: **The main problem is, that I have to give the absolute path to the DLL-function. So I need somewhat of a container where the file lies, which is only readable through my software**. My software should then give a path to the DLL-function. I thoght mayby I could read the file in a virtual  RAM "folder" and work with this copy. So when the software is shut down there will be no file on the PC that could be read.

Comment: The Windows CryptProtectData could bes used to encrypt and decrypt the file. But then I must save the file to a temporary place, to give a link (as string) to the DLL-function. This could of course be done in a hidden folder, but it is not quite safe.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of - and I don't source code for it at hand - is [hash and decrypt](http://rdist.root.org/2007/04/09/mesh-design-pattern-hash-and-decrypt/).

Encrypt your file with anything, using a key derived from a hash of your code. Do not store the key anywhere. Your code is the key. Better yet, hash some memory structure that only a successful run of your program can create.

Chances are it will break each time you update your code, though. You will have to consider 32 bits and 64 bits architectures. Maybe pointer alingment could come into play. Make sure your security requirements are worth the effort, and don't under estimate the maintenance effort.

Usually, CryptProtectData will do, and provide the pOptionalEntropy parameter for added security (then accept @Patrick answer, not mine).